# Layered Navigation

Tags: template, navigation

I have a store that I am developing using Magento CE 1.8.1. On my category pages, I have modified the 2 Column Left Sidebar but I am having an issue.

On the left side bar, I have made a border via css where it shows subcategories, prices, etc. This same border will appear with nothing in it when a category does not have any sub categories.

How would I make no border appear when the category does not have any sub-categories?

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div class="container thirteen columns">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
             <aside class="col-left sidebar three columns"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></aside>
            <section class="col-main twelve columns">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
```

Basically, I am using the 2column-left template and copied into my theme directory. Above, I have where it says aside class="col-left sidebar three columns", my css looks like the following:

```
aside.col-left
{
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    border-right-width: thin;
    padding: 7px 5px 10px 5px;
}
```

I am still new to developing for magento so maybe I am doing it wrong. Any pointers would help?

Comment: Could you show use you template file. Thanks.

Comment: It will be a blind guess work if you don't provide your markup, so post your template for a clear answer.

Comment: Probably before the `foreach` loop and the `div` which contains the subcategories you will have to check if there are subcategories at all. But better show us the template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some another way. Using this code you can easily more clear which is parent category and which one sub-category so just you have to add your class in first loop. 
In my code there is done using ul li tag instead of you can set the div tag.

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul id="nav">
           <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your code did help me alot even though I need to tweak a little bit to fit my design.

Comment: Thanks a lot ya that y I mention you have to change code as your div tag and write css for that

Answer (score 2):

You can add a if condition in your loop as following:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$count = count($category->getChildren());
if($count == 0) {
   --Display div without border--
} else {
   --Display div with border--
}
```